# python numpy `np.take` with 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to take a list of elements from an 2D numpy array with given list of coordinates and I want to avoid using loop. I saw that `np.take` works with 1D array but I can't make it work with 2D arrays.

Example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(a)
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]]

np.take(a, [[1,2]])
# gives [2, 3] but I want just [6]
```

I want to avoid loop because I think that will be slower (I need speed). But if you can persuade  me that a loop is as fast as an existing numpy function solution, then I can go for it.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `a[1].take([2])` Ignoring the index error in your question... this returns `array([6])`

Comment: Then, if I have a list of coordinates, I need to do `[a[i].take(j) for i,j in coords]`, will that be slower if there's a built-in numpy function that can potentially do it?

Comment: How your list of coordinates looks like? Is it like ‘[[y0, x0], [y1, x1], ...]‘ ?

Comment: np.take(a, [[-1]]) but why not just use a slice... a[1, 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have a list of coordinates like this:

```
coords = [[y0, x0], [y1, x1], ...]
```

To get the values of array `a` at these coordinates you need:

```
a[[y0, y1, ...], [x0, x1, ...]]
```

So `a[coords]` will not work. One way to do it is:

```
Y = [c[0] for c in coords]
X = [c[1] for c in coords]
```

or

```
Y = np.transpose(coords)[0]
X = np.transpose(coords)[1]
```

Then

```
a[Y, X]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Exactly what I wanted. I just tested out and it seems like the speed is very similar to `np.take` method along with list comprehension. But still kudos for you!

Answer (score 1):

Does fancy indexing do what you want?  np.take seems to flatten the array before operating.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)

a
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])

rows = [ 1,1,2,0]
cols = [ 0,1,1,2]

# Use the indices to access items in a
a[rows, cols]
# array([4, 5, 8, 3])

a[1,0], a[1,1], a[2,1], a[0,2]
# (4, 5, 8, 3)
```

Comment: How is this different from what I wrote? ;)

Comment: It was written in parallel.  I only saw yours after I posted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Exactly what I wanted. I just tested out and it seems like the speed is very similar to `np.take` method along with list comprehension. Since Andreas K. answered slight faster than you, so I will accept his answer, but still kudos for you!